Paradox of being commanded to not do something when out of control?
One of the principles that comes out in discussions about drinking and doing mitzvot, is that the alcohol impairs one's self control, and thus they aren't doing the mitzva properly [e.g. some sources here].
This presents what seems to be a paradox, because if one loses self control, one cannot be commanded. This is a fundamental principle of Torah and one of the 13 principles of faith, and discussed in our hashkafic works extensively; that a being that is not capable of self control, is not commandable.
Therefore the commandment to not do certain mitzvot while drunk seems to imply that we are never allowed to get drunk, because then we will be in a state where we are uncommandable, and there are commandments that apply to that state!
How to resolve?

Loss of control doesn't have to be 100%.

In order to to be not commandable, one has to be "as drunk as Lot." One who is less intoxicated can still be forbidden to do certain things, like psak halacha, birchas kohanim, tefillah, etc.

I don't think I understand your question. So you assumed that by drinking (or using drugs etc) we enter a state of אנוס רחמנא פטריה and we're "uncommandable", just like sleeping or sleepwalking. What's your problem with willingly entering this state?

According to this shiur, (see from 17:22) it is forbidden to become drunk.

Definitely a valid answer. It does make one wonder why there are halachot for what not to do when one is in a forbidden state.

Because Torah covers everything.
